# В IE7 не работает .animate();

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

```
$('.mod_slideshow_content_container').animate({marginLeft: '-=' + width_main2*4}, 10);
```

Вот эта строчка не работает. Почему-то в ИЕ7... в ИЕ8 все нормально. Ошибок ИЕ7 не выдает, однако не работает. Скрипт писал не я, он из модуля jooml'ы. Кое что лишнее осталось. Вот весь скрипт:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var modSlideShowCurrentSlide = 1;
        var width_main3 = $(".mod_slideshow_content").width();
        var width_main2 = $(".mod_slideshow_content").width();
        var width_main = $(".container").width() - 480;
        $(".mod_slideshow_content_text").css("width", width_main2);
        $(".mod_slideshow_content").css("width", width_main2);
        $("img.slide").css("width", width_main2);

        //Функция для перехода на следующий слайд
        function jumpToNextSlide() {
            if (modSlideShowCurrentSlide < modSlideShowMaxSlide) {
                $('.mod_slideshow_content_container').animate({
                    marginLeft: '-=' + width_main2
                }, 10);
            }
            modSlideShowCurrentSlide++;
            if (modSlideShowCurrentSlide > 5) {
                $('.mod_slideshow_content_container').animate({
                    marginLeft: '0'
                }, 10);
                modSlideShowCurrentSlide = 1;
            }
        }

        //Функция для активации вкладки с идентификатором slideId
        function switchSlide(slideId) {
        }

        //Функция для начала автоматического переключения вкладок
        function startSlideAnimation() {
            intervalID = setInterval(function() { jumpToNextSlide() }, {/literal}{$slide_time}000{literal});
        }

        //Функция для завершения автоматического переключения вкладок
        function stopSlideAnimation() {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }

        //Обработка наведения курсора мыши на номер вкладки
        $("div.mod_slideshow .control_panel .control_panel_links a").hover(

        function () {
            //Останавливаем автоматическое переключение вкладок
            stopSlideAnimation();

            //Определяем порядковый номер вкладки
            var str = $(this).attr('id');
            var id_prefix = "link_";
            var id = str.substring(id_prefix.length, str.length);

            //Включаем слайд с идентификатором id
            switchSlide(id);
        }, function () {
            startSlideAnimation();
        });

        //Запускаем автоматическое переключение вкладок при загрузке страницы
        startSlideAnimation();
        $('.bord_l').click(function () {
            if (modSlideShowCurrentSlide > 1) {
                $('.mod_slideshow_content_container').animate({
                    marginLeft: '+=' + width_main2
                }, 10);
                modSlideShowCurrentSlide--;
            }
            if (modSlideShowCurrentSlide == 1) {
                // switchSlide(modSlideShowCurrentSlide);
                $('.mod_slideshow_content_container').animate({
                    marginLeft: '-=' + width_main2 * 4
                }, 10);
                modSlideShowCurrentSlide = 5;
            }
        });

        $('.bord_r').click(function () {
            if (modSlideShowCurrentSlide < modSlideShowMaxSlide) {
                $('.mod_slideshow_content_container').animate({
                    marginLeft: '-=' + width_main2
                }, 10);
            }
            modSlideShowCurrentSlide++;
            if (modSlideShowCurrentSlide > 5) {
                $('.mod_slideshow_content_container').animate({
                    marginLeft: '0'
                }, 10);
                modSlideShowCurrentSlide = 1;
            }
        });
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все что сходу мне стукнуло бы в голову это

```
$('.mod_slideshow_content_container').animate({marginLeft: '-=' + parseint(width_main2*4)}, 10);
```

На основании того что width_main2 могла получиться стрингового типа, с вследствии чего ишак чудило не вкурил тему. Но это так, мысли в слух не проверял.

Comment: parseint не помогает...

Comment: А в чистом виде пробовали проверить анимацию? В смысле в отдельном документе просто попробовать.

Comment: Пробовал. Отключил все скрипты кроме JQuery. результат тот же. Не работает ничего.

Comment: Версия jquery?

Comment: 1.7. Сначала 1,4 помоему стояла

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается все дело было в верстке. Хотя не точно. Переписал скрипт так, что замена marginLeft делается через element.style.marginLeft. Так все работает.